# КЕшью или кешьЮ?

Tags: фонетика

кЕшью или кешьЮ?

Answer (score 1):

[К**е́**шью](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%D1%8E/) или то же [на грамоте.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%D1%8E).